# Maven creating local repository in the current directory with a '?' subdirectory

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I tried to switch java version on Ubuntu through `update-alternatives`. However, in the process something happened to maven settings. Maven is not using local repository as `<user>/.m2/repository` anymore. Instead, whenever I am running mvn command it is creating a suddirectory with '?' name in the current directory and downloading packages in .m2 path within the  curren_dir/'?' location. How can I fix the original maven settins. `mvn help:effective-settings` also showing the same thing.
I tried to remove and purge maven and reinstall, but that does not solve anything.

Comment: Note, when I switch to the default java version it shows maven points to the right directory

Comment: Is there a local repository definition in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: Yes there is. It is `<user>/.m2/repository`.